# Don't understand how this example one-hot code indexes a numpy array with [i,j] when j is a tuple?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I don't get how the line: `results[i, sequence] = 1` works in the following.

I am following along in the debugger with some sample code in a Manning book: "Deep Learning with Python" (Example 3.5-classifying-movie-reviews.ipynb from the book) and while I understand what the code does, I don't get the syntax or how it works. I'm trying to learn Python and Deep learning together and want to understand what the code is doing.

```
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    # Create an all-zero matrix of shape (len(sequences), dimension)
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.  # <--- How does this work?
    return results
```

- This creates `results`, a 25,000 x 10,000 array of zeros.
- **`sequences` is a list-of-tuples, for example (3, 0, 5). It then walks `sequences` and for each non-zero value of each sequence, set the corresponding index in `results[i]` to 1.0. They call it one-hot encoding.**
- **I don't understand how the line: `results[i, sequence] = 1`
  accomplishes this in numpy.**
- I get the `for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences)` part: just enumerating the `sequences` list and keeping track of `i`.
- I'm guessing there is some numpy magic that is somehow setting values in `results[i]` based on examining `sequence[n]` element by element and inserting a 1.0 whenever `sequence[n]` is non-zero(?) Just want to understand the syntax.

Comment: Can you provide example(s) for `sequences` and `dimension`?

Comment: and what I don't understand is why they claim that this code sets 1 "for each non-zero value of each sequence"? it sets 1 for every value of sequence

Comment: No it doesn't set 1 for every value of `sequence`.  It only sets 1 at the 2D array location `results[i, sequence]`; all the other 9999 values in that row will remain zero, i.e. all the other 9999 values `results[i, j]` for j != sequence. Your question boils down to [***"How does 2D array indexing work in numpy?"***](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html) ; please read that scipy/numpy doc.

Comment: You keep referring to `results[i]` as if it was a single value; it's not, it's a (big) row of an array with 10,000 values. Think of it as `results[i, j]` for j = 0...10000

Comment: @smci "sequence" is an element of "sequences" and it is a tuple. for example (3, 0, 5). "each non-zero value of sequence" is 3 and 5. the code sets 1 for [i, 3], [i, 0] and [i, 5], not just [i, 3] and [i, 5]

Comment: @mangusta: Ah, thanks. Then that should be edited into the question. But note that even if `sequence` is a tuple, its indices don't cover all values in one row of `results[i, ...]`

Comment: So I edited the question with that crucial missing information. Also for clarity. OP please ask questions in the most concise form possible, we don't need to know all about where the code came from. You're asking how the indexing `results[i, j] = value` works on a numpy array, when j is a tuple.

Comment: And it isn't only when `sequence[n]` is non-zero; j=0 is a perfectly legitimate index value too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422410/standard-implementation-of-vectorize-sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `sequence` is a list of integers,

```
results[i,sequence] = 1
```

is equivalent to

```
for j in sequence:
    results[i][j] = 1
```

Comment: Also see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing for an explanation how indexing arrays with sequences works.

Comment: Thats what I expected, but didn't see how that could happen without the second loop. At least for a beginner that syntax is not intuitive. Thanks for breaking it down for me.

Answer (score 2):

So I am going to make a few assumptions because you did not provide an example of sequences or dimension. I am assuming dimension is the highest possible value + 1 in `sequences` and each value in `sequences` is either an integer or a `tuple` of integers.

This goes through each sequence, and sets all the values in the `i'th` row to `1.0` where the indicies are in `sequence`.

```py
# Create an all-zero matrix of shape (len(sequences), dimension)
results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
    results[i, sequence] = 1.  # How does this work?
return results
```

So walking through it with these inputs:

```py
import numpy as np
sequences = [(2, 3), (2, 1), 4]
dimension = 5 # max value is 4, +1 is 5
results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
print(results)
#[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
     results[i, sequence] = 1.0
print(results)
#[[0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
# [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

For the first sequence `(2, 3)` it replaced the 3rd and 4th items in the array with `1.0`

For the second sequence `(1, 2)` it replaced the 2nd and 3rd items in the array with `1.0`

For the last sequence `4` replaced the 5th item with `1.0`

Comment: Thanks, the example you gave is quite helpful. For the example in the book, the sequence is all integer values (representing words in a dict) i.e. the word "later" is 300, the word "takes" is 301 ... Trying to do binary classification of text. So each movie review's text is converted to an array of ints. The dict contains the 10,000 most common words, with the word being the key, and a unique int the value. Kinda wonky, but just illustrating the problem. Thanks again for the quick and useful response.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before, then I found it's because `results` is a numpy array not a list. So within a numpy array you could update it by `results[i,sequence] = 1`, where `sequence` is a list of index. But within a list you couldn't do it.